# How can I sometimes redirect before a form post?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, http-post

I have a form which is in a sidebar, and shows on multiple pages. If the user is on `page-a.php` and submits the form, it uses ajax to return some data to a div on that page.

However, if the user is on `page-b.php` and submits the same form (again, it is included on both pages), I want the form to redirect to `page-a.php` and then use the same ajax post to load the data.  How can I achieve this?

Edit for clarity:

page-a.php - when this submits this form (included from separate file), an ajax call is made to page-c.php, which loads data into the div:

```
<form method="post" action="page-c.php">
    <input ....
               />
</form>
<div></div>
```

page-b.php has the exact same form (included from a separate file), but different content, so in order to load the data into the div, we need to redirect to page-a.php:

```
<form method="post" action="page-c.php">
   <input .....
          />
</form>
```

So how can I make the form call work the same (ajax that is already implemented), but have it redirect me to page-a.php first?

Comment: You wouldn't need to use ajax to accomplish it.

Comment: @brenjt the ajax is for the form's data retrieval, not the redirect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it using this:

```
<form name="formA" id="formA"  method="post" 
            <?php if(curPageName() == 'page-a.php'){
                echo 'class="ajax" action="page-c.php"';
                }
                else {
                echo 'action="page-a.php"';
                }
            ?>
        >
```

with this on page-a.php to auto submit the form on page load, which redirects the load to the ajax submit

```
<script type="text/javascript">$(document).ready(function() {document.formA.submitbutton.click(); });</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about having page-b.php's form post to page-a.php, then based on the HTTP_REFERRER cgi environment variable's contents, include some javascript to do you ajax post routine on page load?

If you do a real HTTP Redirect, you will lose all of your form data that was filled in on page-b.php.  If they were on the same server, I suppose you could save the data locally and associate it with a session variable, prior to the Http Redirect response.  The page-a.php would check for the local form data when it loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just extract that JavaScript from `page-a.php` into a separate .js file that is included in both `page-a.php` and `page-b.php`?  Then when the form is submitted it'll just use the same function.  Update that function to take as a parameter the page that is making the call, so that you don't update the div on `page-b.php`.

Answer (score 0):

Have your form tag set as so

```
<form action="page-a.php" method="post">
    <input name="formfield" id="formfield" />
</form>
```

on `page-b.php` you could use php to pull the posted data from the form.

```
<?php echo $_POST['formfield'];?>
```

You wouldn't need to use javascript/ajax for any of this.

Comment: I'm already using ajax, and it works nicely. Aka, the form, when on `page-a.php` posts via ajax and gets the data. I need the same thing to happen from `page-b.php`, but to redirect to `page-a.php` first.

Comment: Edited the question to clarify